# Why Dynamic cast giving Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base 
{
   virtual void display(){}
};

class child : public base {};

int main()
{
   base *obj;
   child *ob = dynamic_cast<child*>(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program has undefined behavior since you are using an uninitialized variable.

Initialize `obj` to something sensible and things should work. E.g.

```
base* obj = new child;
child* ob = dynamic_cast<child*>(obj);
```